# Package PayPal 1.7.4 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0

Tags: paypal, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

In my `ASP.NET Core 1.0` app I'm trying to install a `PayPal .NET SDK` [from here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki). But I'm getting the above error. Their [prerequisite here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Installation) says only 4.0 or later is required. Similar error occurs when I try to install paypal-sdk-core-dotnet [described here](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet). Note: I'm using `VS2015-Update3`.

**project.json**:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "PayPal": "1.7.4",
    "PayPalCoreSDK": "1.7.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't use it. Minimum for netstandard Library is .NET 4.5 (which has System.Runtime, older .NET Frameworks don't have it). And even then, you can't target .NET Core. You have to wait until PayPal makes a netcore library, or you target .NET 4.5 (i.e. `net451`) or newer instead of `netcoreapp1.0`

Comment: @Tseng Per your comment and a response from Shaun Luttin, I changed the target to .NET 4.6.1 and it's working now - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your frameworks section to this:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net451": {}
},
```

And delete this from your dependencies section:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "platform"
},
```

Why?

The PayPal SDK uses parts of .NET Framework 4.5.1 that are not included in the [.NET Standard Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library) version 1.6. Since .NET Core implements .NET Standard 1.6, it does not support the PayPal SDK.

Comment: Is what you are suggesting equivalent to: Creating a Web project in VS2015 using the built-in project template `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)` as opposed to the built-in project template `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)`?

Comment: @nam Yes. My suggestion is equivalent to that.

Comment: Thank you for providing a way to convert an existing VS2015 web project that was created using one type of project template to a project that would have been created using another type of project template.

Comment: @nam You're welcome. The small difference between what I suggested and what the VS2015 Core Web Application (.NET Framework) template provides is that my suggestion targets .NET 4.5.1 whereas the built-in template targets .NET 4.6.1. Both target the Full Framework though instead of targeting .NET Core and that's the important change.

Comment: You are correct about the .NET version difference. It's working now.